# Why FCM slow down the app start up?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently I upgrade the GCM service in my app to FCM. But after the upgrading it takes about 20 seconds to start up the app. However, before the upgrading it takes only 1 or 2 second(s). Anyone know why this happen and how to speed up the start up?

Comment: and I am sure I do not add the whole fcm package as the dependecy, I only use the FCM-Messaging package.

Comment: is your app already crossed 64k limit?

Comment: @JayShah Yes, and I use muli dev.

Comment: If you are using instant run in android  studio with multidex support then it will reduce app start up speed in debug build.So that may be issue.